# Energy Renormalization and Vacuum Diagrams

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, renormalization, s-matrix-theory, ground-state

I have been reading the lecture notes of Coleman's course on QFT. When developing scattering theory with the use of a cutoff function, he mentions that, in order to ensure that the free vacuum scatters into the free vacuum $\langle 0|S|0\rangle=1$, we must add an energy renormalization term $H_I\mapsto H_I-a$. Moreover, since before adding this term $\langle 0|S|0\rangle\sim e^{-iE_0 T}$, with $T$ the time scale in which the interaction was turned on and $E_0$ the energy of the true vacuum state, he argues that $a$ is precisely this energy. Moreover, it is computed precisely by summing up vacuum diagrams. This seems like a very useful tool! It is there to force the ground state energies of both the free and full Hamiltonians coincide. However, why should one force this?

When discussing the LSZ formalism however, such a term does not appear. Instead, vacuum diagrams disappear because we have to divide by $\langle 0|U_I(-\infty,\infty)|0\rangle$ when computing Heisenberg Green's functions. However, in that proof it is assumed both that the free Hamiltonian aniquilates the free vacuum and the interacting Hamiltonian aniquilates the interacting vacuum. Again, why do we want both vacuums to have zero energy? By doing this it seems like we loose the information on the energy difference between them. Can $\langle 0|U_I(\infty,-\infty)|0\rangle$ still be interpreted as the energy difference between these two vacua?